# Import csv with different structures into a Dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm not quite sure how to solve my problem. I have a csv file which is structured as follows.

```
def1_begin,,,,
key1, value1,,,
key2, value2,,,
...
def1_end,,,,
def2_begin,,,
key3, value3,,,
key4, value4,,,
...
def2_end,,,,
global1_begin,,,,
key5, xyz5, xya5, xyz1, xss5
key6, dsa6, fdf6, fdf6, sda5
global1_end
```

I have these start and end lines as a separation in the file. Now how can I best read this into a dictionary so that I can use the parameters in the program. In the end this is an information file for my main program.

Comment: Did you try using the `csv` module from the standard library?

Comment: Yes i can use the csv module or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

```
output_dict = {}  # here will you get all values
_file_part = None  # value storing part of the file that you are parsing

with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip("\n").rstrip(",")  # get rid of line break and commas at the end of line
        # check whether you start to read a new data block
        if line.endswith("_begin"):
            _file_part = line
        # check whether you end to read a data block
        elif line.endswith("_end"):
            _file_part = None
        # put data into data block
        else:
            key, *values = line.split(", ")
            output_dict.setdefault(_file_part, {}).update({key: values})
```

You will get all the data into output_dict variable.

With this file as input:

```
def1_begin,,,,
key1, value1,,,
key2, value2,,,
def1_end,,,,
def2_begin,,,
key3, value3,,,
key4, value4,,,
def2_end,,,,
global1_begin,,,,
key5, xyz5, xya5, xyz1, xss5
key6, dsa6, fdf6, fdf6, sda5
global1_end
```

I extracted following values to output_dict:

```
{'def1_begin': {'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value2']},
 'def2_begin': {'key3': ['value3'], 'key4': ['value4']},
 'global1_begin': {'key5': ['xyz5', 'xya5', 'xyz1', 'xss5'],
                   'key6': ['dsa6', 'fdf6', 'fdf6', 'sda5']}}
```

PS. You can OrderedDict instead of dict, if position of the variable matters.

Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks :) Is it still easy to solve that the dictionary only contains the lines between end and start? The dictionary can be named Def1, Def2.

Comment: yeah, you can refactor it a bit, for example:  
rename your dicts (add at the end): ```def1 = output_dict.pop("def1_begin")```  
or change names of dictionary keys ```file_part = line[:-6]```

Comment: One more question. The global part is more like a table. Is it easier to make a table or dataframe from the dictionary then. Or should you do that from the beginning?

Comment: You have tutorial how to create dataFrame with pandas (one of examples is 100% matching this case): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
Surely, you can do that with these dictionary values (maybe after minor rework).